# How to use gpt to fix corrupted APFS container?

Tags: terminal, disk-utility, partition, apfs, efi

My 1TB SSD failed on me with what appears to be a corrupted APFS container. I found [a post here on stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340097/apfs-partition-inaccessible-container-missing) that suggests to remove and create GPT entries but the values in the example are specific to the case of that post. I need help understanding what values to use and which GPT entries to remove and add.

I will provide the same information that the original poster linked above did and extensive information about my disk after:

[The post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340097/apfs-partition-inaccessible-container-missing) suggests "To correct the GPT, you need to remove the second and third entries" with:

```
sudo gpt remove -i 2 /dev/disk0
sudo gpt remove -i 3 /dev/disk0
```

And then "The command below will add the APFS container to the GPT."

```
sudo gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 1875036440 -t apfs /dev/disk0
```

So my actual question is - what numbers should I use as input here to remove and add gpt entries? I assume that the numbers there are specific to the post he replied to but I can't find "1875036440" referenced anywhere there. And it looks to me like he suggests to remove two entries but only add one? What should I do in my case?

This is the result of **diskutil list disk2** on my disk:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         377.0 GB   disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS MEDIA                   622.9 GB   disk2s3
```

There are 2 partitions, APFS is the OS which doesn't work and HFS is MEDIA which still mounts fine.

And this is the result of **sudo gpt -r show disk2** on my disk:

```
gpt show: disk2: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         MBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640   736324336      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   736733976  1216529008      3  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1953262984      262150         
  1953525134          32         Sec GPT table
  1953525166           1         Sec GPT header
```

This is the result of **sudo dd if=/dev/disk2 bs=512 count=1 skip=409640 | hexdump -Cv**

```
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes transferred in 0.004883 secs (104852 bytes/sec)
00000000  c2 f9 f4 f8 b1 61 fd 24  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.....a.$........|
00000010  5d 7f 5c 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 80 00 00 00 00  |].\.............|
00000020  4e 58 53 42 00 10 00 00  5e 6d 7c 05 00 00 00 00  |NXSB....^m|.....|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  3e 87 ef 07 9e 5b 40 14  |........>....[@.|
00000050  89 f7 e7 da ca 29 7d 4c  13 f8 7c 00 00 00 00 00  |.....)}L..|.....|
00000060  5e 7f 5c 00 00 00 00 00  18 01 00 00 2c 6c 00 00  |^.\.........,l..|
00000070  34 21 9f 02 00 00 00 00  2c 80 9e 02 00 00 00 00  |4!......,.......|
00000080  3a 00 00 00 04 0d 00 00  38 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |:.......8.......|
00000090  ca 0c 00 00 3a 00 00 00  d3 ef 03 00 00 00 00 00  |....:...........|
000000a0  73 7c 0b 00 00 00 00 00  01 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |s|..............|
000000b0  00 00 00 00 64 00 00 00  03 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....d...........|
000000c0  06 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  ca ef 03 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000d0  c1 93 04 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000100  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000130  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000140  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000160  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000190  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000200
```

And this is the result of **sudo dd if=/dev/disk2 bs=512 count=1 skip=736733976 | hexdump -Cv**

```
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes transferred in 0.004882 secs (104878 bytes/sec)
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000080  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000100  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000130  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000140  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000160  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000190  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000200
```

Trying to run First Aid on the OS partition gives me this:

```
Running First Aid on “” (disk2s2)

Repairing storage system
Performing fsck_apfs -y -x /dev/disk2s2
Checking the container superblock.
Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
error: (oid 0x401) nr: invalid o_oid (0x7d11eb)
error: (oid 0x401) nr: invalid o_type (0x80000003, expected 0x80000011)
error: verification/reading of the nx_reaper object failed: Illegal byte sequence
The volume /dev/disk2s2 could not be verified completely.
Storage system check exit code is 8.
Storage system verify or repair failed. : (-69716)

Operation failed…
```

Trying to run First Aid on the AppleAPFSMedia gives me this:

```
Running First Aid on “AppleAPFSMedia” (disk3)

Fixing damaged partition map.
Invalid disk.

Operation failed…
```

Some background info:
This all started with my Macbook Pro (2012, latest Mojave) having some hickups not long ago where the screen would freeze for a minute or two and then go back to normal. Then one time it just got really slow and froze up every 10 seconds so I tried to shut it down but it would only shut down to a black screen with the mouse pointer still on the screen and stayed there for over an hour. I decided to force it to power off by holding the power button but when I turned it back on I then got the dreaded "no entry" sign. I held cmd+v for verbose and got told that it could not find the APFS boot partition.

If you made it this far - thank you for reading, any input is greatly appreciated!