# Time Machine Backups hidden files

Tags: time-machine

The other day, I transferred my Time Machine Backups from one memory card to another, but an issue arose. The memory card with the original Time Machine files had all together nine items (folders and files, some hidden). The card they were transferred to showed only seven items. Two items (hidden folders) were not transferred. These were .DocumentRevisions-v100, and .Temporaryitems. I'm not sure how to treat this.
My question: is there a special way to transfer these, other than the normal route. If not, why didn't these folders get transferred? Also is there a way to fix this?
Any help with this issue will be appreciated.
Thanks...

Comment: How did you do the transfer?

Comment: @mmmmmm Drag and drop

Comment: That does not work - as TM are not simple sets of files see if https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/442544/is-it-possible-to-copy-an-entire-apfs-format-time-machine-disk-to-another-drive helps