# Copy Time Machine backups from HD to SSD

Tags: mac, time-machine

I'm retiring my old slow Time Machine HD in favor of a new SSD.  The new SSD is working fine (in Sonoma), but how do I copy the old HD backups (I want to keep) to the new SSD so I can turn off the HD?  Finder rejects them for dragging.  I have read that rsync cannot do it.  Is there another way?  Thanks.

Comment: How about Terminal/tmutil or Disk Utility?

Comment: What are the formats (HFS+ or APFS) of the HD and the SSD?

Comment: Both are APFS (Case-sensitive, Encrypted).

Comment: Apple Support agent says: "I believe the best way to go would be to first format the disk as a Time Machine disk, and then manually moving the folders from one disk to the other. If that doesn't preserve the Time Machine back ups then it seems that we cannot perform the transfer even with a terminal command." ???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I replace my smaller Time Machine Drive with a New Drive on macOS Ventura (Encrypted)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/463617/how-do-i-replace-my-smaller-time-machine-drive-with-a-new-drive-on-macos-ventura) Basically, you can no longer move a Time Machine since they changed the underlying format from HFS to APFS. You just have to keep the old one on a shelf.

Comment: Yes, thanks to all. It is impossible. I'll just unplug the old one, and plug it in again if I find I need something old.